# Cordova request permission throwing exception

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, mobile

I am using cordova custom plugin to check permission for as the sdk version is migrated from 22 to 23. I am unable to find and  override onRequestPermissionResult.

```
       NoSuchMethodException when delivering permissions results java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onRequestPermissionResult
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:640)
    at com.phonegap.plugins.xxxxx.xxxxx.deliverPermissionResult(xxxxx.java:314)
    at com.phonegap.plugins.xxxxx.xxxxx.execute(xxxxx.java:218)
    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:95)
    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:131)
    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:59)

at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemExposedJsApi.exec(SystemExposedJsApi.java:41)
at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Some Context

> Note: If the app targets API level 23 or higher, the app user must
>   explicitly grant this permission to the app through a permission
>   management screen.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855612/request-permission-in-android-cordova-plugin-does-not-prompt-the-user).

[Android Plugin Development Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html).

[Developing Cordova apps](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_developing_cordova_apps.html).

Is this the methodb your looking for ?:[CordovaPlugin.java](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaPlugin.java)
.

```
    public void onRequestPermissionResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                          int[] grantResults) throws JSONException {

}
```

**Enabling a Cordova app to support Android SDK version 23 permissions can be found** [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/t_cord_enable_android_23_perm.html).

## Procedure

(1) Update your third-party Cordova plug-ins to a version that supports requesting permissions at runtime.

(2) Add the `PermissionHelper.java` file. This file is a dependency for any plug-in that uses the Android SDK version 23 permissions. If
you do not have any third-party `Cordova` plug-ins that depend on permissions, then you do not need to add the `PermissionHelper.java` file.

(a) Create an org.apache.cordova package.

(b) Download the PermissionHelper.java file from the Apache [cordova-plugin-compat](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-compat) GitHub repository at: 
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-compat/blob/master/src/android/PermissionHelper.java.

(c) Add the `PermissionHelper.java` file into the package directory that you created in step 2.a. You only need to add the `PermissionHelper.java` file to your project once, even if you have more than one third-party plug-in.

> This class (`PermissionHelper.java`) provides reflective methods for permission requesting and
>   checking so that plugins written for cordova-android 5.0.0+ can still
>   compile with earlier cordova-android versions.

**Here is a look inside the source code for** [PermissionHelper.java](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-compat/blob/master/src/android/PermissionHelper.java):

`onRequestPermissionResult()` is **not** a method of `PermissionHelper.java`, it is invoked from there.
This is a helper method alternative to `cordovaInterface.requestPermission()`.

Here is how it is called:

```
    private static void deliverPermissionResult(CordovaPlugin plugin, int requestCode, String[] permissions) {
        // Generate the request results
        int[] requestResults = new int[permissions.length];
        Arrays.fill(requestResults, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

        try {
            Method onRequestPermissionResult = CordovaPlugin.class.getDeclaredMethod(
                    "onRequestPermissionResult", int.class, String[].class, int[].class);

onRequestPermissionResult.invoke(plugin, requestCode, permissions, requestResults);
...
```

[CordovaInterfaceImpl](https://dff-solutions.github.io/dff-cordova-plugin-location/org/apache/cordova/CordovaInterfaceImpl.html)